# Chromium Login Bug

Tags: 14.04, chromium

Every time I start Chromium I get:

Your profile could not be opened correctly. (repeated in many different pop-up windows--6 to be precise).

I have to then sign in (again).

Please help.

Here is more information that arises when I run chromium from command line:

```
chromium-browser
[9784:9810:0924/204936:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)] Web sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA journal_mode = PERSIST
[9784:9784:0924/204936:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)]  sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA journal_mode = PERSIST
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[9784:9810:0924/204937:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)] Web sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA cache_size=32
[9784:9810:0924/204937:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)] Web sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR)
[9784:9810:0924/204937:ERROR:web_data_service_backend.cc(54)] Cannot initialize the web database: 1
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)]  sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA cache_size=32
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:connection.cc(1060)]  sqlite error 5, errno 0: database is locked, sql: CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR)
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:password_store_factory.cc(135)] Could not initialize login database.
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[9784:9784:0924/204937:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[9784:9784:0924/204941:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
[9784:9784:0924/204941:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(769)] Not implemented reached in virtual void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::InitModalType(ui::ModalType)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by closing chrome and then runnning:

```
find ~/.config/google-chrome/ -name LOCK -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that no process is using your profile. Close all Chromium windows and then in a terminal run

```
$ killall -9 chromium-browser
```

Then start Chromium again. If you still get the same error then there is a possibility that your profile was corrupted. You can create a new one closing Chromium and running

```
$ mv ~/.config/chromium ~/chromium_profile_backup
```

This will move your current profile to your home folder (you can later decide what to do with it). The next time you start Chromium it will create a new profile.

Please note that your download history, bookmarks (if not synced online), history, etc will be gone.

Comment: I had tried the profile change before without luck (I mean it worked, but then the problem came back the next time I restarted the browser).

Comment: And I just tried the killall suggestion without any luck.  It seems around 2010 there were many threads about a similar issue, but so far none of the fixes then work now.

Comment: I started having this same problem with Google Chrome a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Got it fixed executing:

```
cd ~/.config/chromium
find . -type f -exec file {} + | grep -i SQLite | cut -d: -f1 | while read FILE; do
    fuser -k -TERM "$FILE"
done
```